# Association between two distributions where only tails matter

Tags: contingency-tables, association-measure

I have two bell shaped (but not normally distributed) data sets, A and B. In these, most of the values in the middle can not be trusted, i.e. they are probably noise. I am interested in knowing how much the individuals that are in the upper tail in A are also in the upper tail in B, and the same for the lower tails.

It is not clear to me what approach to follow. The most sound way seems to categorize the data, for instance, in each dataset i say whether a value falls in the upper 2%, in the lower 2% or in the middle. Then, I can build a contingency table, that could look for instance like this:

```
             lower.1%.A    middle.A    upper.1%.A   
lower.1%.B           20          70             0
middle.B             68        5678            69
upper.1%.B            2          67            21
```

With this table, I can compute a Cramer's V score, to measure association. In the case above, association seems fairly high. Cramer's V is highly significant ($p<10^{-16}$), but its value is quite low (0.21), in principle indicating a poor association.

An alternative option would be to consider only the corner values, e.g.:

```
             lower.1%.A    upper.1%.A   
lower.1%.B           20             0
upper.1%.B            2            21
```

Then, the value of Cramer's V is much higher (0.86) and it is still significant ($p = 10^{-8}$).

It is not clear to me what are the implications of using one or the other approach. What one would you use? I am also open to completely different suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: If you have large samples; weak effects can be highly significant. ... but I wouldn't necessarily call that V "poor".

Answer (score 1):

Your second analysis is a conditional analysis, conditioned on A or B being extreme (loosely speaking). This conditioning throws away the vast majority of your data, so I wouldn't be surprised if the computed statistics are quite different. You'll have to think hard as to whether this bivariate conditioning makes sense in your research context. You'll be making inferences about a different subpopulation than the one you started with, and you'll have to make a statement like, "given that both A or B are extreme, they tend to be extreme together in the same direction."